# User was able to answer a question while it was "on hold"

Tags: bug, on-hold

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58659777/what-will-be-solution-of-below-program-in-python) was put "on hold" as "too broad." The OP edited the question to show their code, but someone was able to add an answer while it was still "on hold."

What could cause this?

[image]

Comment: The problem is, I think I might have added an answer after a question got closed one time, but though "Hmm, oh well. I must be making it up." Now I'm not so sure.

Comment: IIRC there's a grace period where answers that started being written while the question was still open can be submitted even though the question was just closed.

Comment: Reported several times before.  https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: It's not really caching, it's a 4-hour grace period. If you disable JavaScript and load the page before answering, you bypass the client-side check on purpose, or it fails for another reason, you can answer closed questions.